# Genetic Algorithm

Tags: python, constrained-optimization, evolutionary

Is there any Python library as published on PyPi, with genetic algorithm (GA) or GA inspired solver that helps with constrained optimization?
I am aware of Matlab's GA solver and also aware that costs of constraint violations can form part of my objective to minimize. But wanted to check if there's a library that can run on Python where I can specify the objective and an array of constraints.

Comment: not sure if these help; [scipy.optimize.differential_evolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) and in PyPI [geneticalgorithm 1.0.2](https://pypi.org/project/geneticalgorithm/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PyGAD](https://pygad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) seems to be a decent library, although I have never tested it myself. The documentation looks very complete, with good [examples](https://pygad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README_pygad_ReadTheDocs.html#examples-2).

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly what you are needing, but DEAP allows to pass constraints as a decorator: https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/advanced/constraints.html .

Answer (score 5):

Try optapy.

No genetic algorithms, but several other, more advanced metaheuristics. See https://www.optapy.org for more info.